# BOOLEAN Data type Program code

Tags: c++, turbo-c++

Write a program which allows the user to drive if age is greater than 18 and he/she has insurance. (Use nested if and bool data type)

I have tried much but turbo c++ is not declaring bool data type. please write a simple code for this.

Comment: So what? `#define int bool` and then `#define true 1` and `#define false 0`

Comment: Use a compiler that's at least somewhat C++98 compatible. Really old compilers do not support C++ and then possibly do not have bool. Also, double-check that you're using C++ mode.

Comment: Its not working please write a full code for this question

Comment: I have checked. yes it is c++ mode

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I got the question correctly, but here is my answer...

This is the function:

```
bool allowedDriving(int age){
    if(age >= 18){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is the call from main():

```
int main(void){
    int age = 20;

    if(allowedDriving(age)){
        printf("allowed\n");
    }else{
        printf("not allowed\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not just `return age >= 18;`?

Comment: just to make it cleaner to understand

Comment: There is nothing useful or helpful about doing someones homework for them.

Comment: if you wrote the function after the point of calling it, you must declare it at the very top

Comment: is this the reason i got downvoted ... ok i'll know from now on ... sorry, my bad :)